# No transparency in rendered background, is this a bug?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Suddenly I only get a gray background in my cycles renders, even though film-->transparent has been checked and the format is a PNG with RGBA enabled. The image still contains the alpha information (verified in another software) but why is Blender displaying this gray background?

Here is 20 sec video demonstrating the problem:
https://youtu.be/1FqZaiTiCFU

Comment: Did it used to work okay in the same version of blender? And have you installed any new addons/updated any recent drivers, etc?

Comment: I downloaded an older version (2.68) just to test it out.. Same thing. Could this be a Linux "feature"? I usually work on a Windows machine but I'm trying to migrate to Linux Mint at the moment.

Comment: Hmm okay, are you sure that it's not just Linux's way of displaying transparency? Try saving the Image and opening in an image editor go see. Far out I know but worth a shot :)

Comment: I submitted a bug report.. They could not reproduce the behaviour yet, so it seems like it might be a bug.

Comment: Most certainly not a linux feature (I use linux). The idea that the operating system controls or cares about the way an alpha channel is represented sounds quite silly to me to be honest.. ;)

Comment: It might sound silly but it wasn't so far from the truth since it looks like it was a driver issue -which is kind of related to the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a bug report and did some testing. Seems like the cause of this problem might have to do with my graphics drivers.